# Как убить спящие коннекты к БД?

Tags: mysql, linux

Ситуация такая: Есть некий движок магазина, который хостится, среди прочего, у меня на сервере и хронически не закрывает коннекты с MySQL. Как результат, имеются целые простыни спящих коннектов, растущие с каждым новым посетителем, а БД жрёт память как не в себя. Понятно, что надо пинать людей, родивших на свет эту отрыжку веб-разработки, а в идеале и вовсе менять движок, но хотелось бы сделать такую ситуацию невозможной в принципе.

Потому вопросы:

- Какой командой убиваются коннекты к mysql?
- Как получить список коннектов, открытых более N минут назад?
- Можно ли настроить БД так, чтобы она сама принудительно закрывала старые коннекты?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)[MySQL: как посмотреть процессы (подключения) или "снять" конкретный процесс (подключение)](http://how-it.ru/public/root/67-mysql__kak_posmotret_protsessy__podklyucheniya__ili__snyat__konkretnyi_protsess__podklyuchenie_.html). Еще можно посмотреть дополнительно: [зомби-процессы в Линух](http://ramzess.ru/kak-najti-i-ubit-zombie-process/)
2) выше указал
3) да - погуглите

Comment: 3) HINT: ключевое слово timeout (:

Comment: @Justicet, по крайней мере у меня Ваша ссылка на MySQL... не работает.

А причем здесь зомби?

Зомби -- это уже *завершившийся* процесс.

Comment: @MrClon, @avp и нафига? Я вопрос же закрыл. В частности, потому, что ему почти год, как и ответу. Когда я открывал ссылки -- они работали.